# Downloading OLE object from Access database

Tags: python, ms-access

Hi I have simple database in sql connected to Access. I have column Attachment. I need to download all the files from that database from column attachment those attachments are OLE objects. In Access I can click on object, copy it and paste to folder. But I can't do it automatically via python.

I know that most of attachments are .msg files, so that's why I tried to save it like that. But it would be great if it would be possible to just download file with any extension, because i know that there are also .jpg files.
Type of "attachment" is <class 'memoryview'> and it doesn't work.
(I have to do this by Access I cant connect straight to sql database)

I tried to convert it to bytes and then save it, but nothing works.

Im tring smth like that

````
import win32com.client

accessApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(r"path to Accesss DB")

conn = win32com.client.Dispatch("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open(accessApp.CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString)
cursor = win32com.client.Dispatch("ADODB.Recordset")
query = "SELECT * FROM tablename;"
cursor.Open(query, conn)
cursor.MoveFirst()

attachment = cursor.Fields("Attachment").Value

with open("attachment_file_name.msg", "wb") as f:
     f.write(attachment)```
````

Comment: Those aren't OLE objects. `.msg` is the extension of Outlook message files. The code you posted *is connecting to SQL Server directly* anyway - it extracts the connection string from Access then uses it to create an OLEDB connection and connect directly to SQL Server. Why do that at all? Why not use pyodbc to connect to SQL Server ant retrieve those blobs?

Comment: In my company  I cant use pyodbc, dunno why, but its blocked. In access I see those object as OLE

Comment: What do you mean "nothing works"? Do you get an error? Incomprehensible data? Something else? If it's an OLE object and the type is not "Long binary data", extracting the underlying data can be hard. And even more mysterious, assuming this is a linked table, why can Access connect to SQL server just fine but is it not possible for Python to connect to SQL server?

Comment: I mean that i cant read the file that im saving. Yes, it is not possible due to my company policy, I cant install pyodbc library.